# Syntax error only occuring after saving p5.js sketch

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I am experimenting with code found on openprocessing.org by the user Alex (https://www.openprocessing.org/user/74843).

The code executes just fine if I run it in an unsaved sketch in Processing using p5.js mode, but as soon as I try to save the project to open it later it gives syntax errors and refuses to run. I'm stumped as the code seemed to run just fine prior to saving the project.

Does anyone know what is causing this?

The compiler gives me the following error:

> SyntaxError: Expected ; but found poly

The code is below:

```
// polygon array and number of verts
let poly = [];
let n = 100;

// canvas size variables
let w = 500;
let h = 500;

// setup and draw functions ---

function setup() {
  createCanvas(w, h);
  strokeWeight(12);
  noFill();
  cursor(HAND);
  noStroke();
  n++; // add extra point for closing the polygon

  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    // populate regular polygon vertices given number of points n
    let a = {
      x: (w/2) + 100*sin(map(i, 0, n-1, 0, TAU)),
      y: (h/2) + 100*cos(map(i, 0, n-1, 0, TAU))
    };
    poly.push(a);
  }      
}

function draw() {
  // use default blend mode for background
  blendMode(BLEND);
  background(0, 0, 0);

  // use additive blend mode to separate color channels
  blendMode(ADD);
  stroke(255, 0, 0);
  drawPoly(1000, 1000);

  stroke(0, 255, 0);
  drawPoly(1200, 1500);

  stroke(0, 0, 255);
  drawPoly(2000, 1700);    
} 

// helper function implementations ---

function logMap(value, start1, stop1, start2, stop2) {
  // based off of linear regression + existing p5.map function

  start2 = log(start2);
  stop2 = log(stop2);

  return exp(start2 + (stop2 - start2) * ((value - start1) / (stop1 - start1)));
}

function drawPoly(dx, dy) {
  // draws polygon given vertices in the poly[] array, adds mouse bias using params

  let g = 0;
  if (mouseIsPressed)
    g = random(-2, 2);

  beginShape();
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    let bias = dist(mouseX, mouseY, poly[i].x, poly[i].y);
    vertex(poly[i].x + dx / logMap(bias, w, 0, dx, 45) + g, poly[i].y + dy / logMap(bias, h, 0, dy, 45) + g);
  }
  endShape();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I opened up the project in Sublime Text Editor instead and ran it on a local server using WAMP/MAMP and the javascript runs just fine.

I believe this error was caused by the Processing client trying to build the necessary files ( index.html for example ).

Still not sure what caused the error but simply working with p5js outside of the Processing client solved the issues in this case.